# how do i remove the random words from this Anagram from youtube

Tags: java, android

i follow the step from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qo6cdULtWik an Anagram game. but i want to remove the random words so after i answered all question from dictionary it will end so that the question will not repeat

```
package com.example.child.fragments;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.plattysoft.leonids.ParticleSystem;
import com.plattysoft.leonids.modifiers.ScaleModifier;

import com.example.child.sidenavigation.R;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;


/**
 * Created by Child on 7/4/2017.
 */

public class Anagram extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView tv_info,tv_word;
    EditText et_guess;
    Button b_check;

    Random r;

    String currentWord;

    String[] dictionary = {
            "one",
            "two",
            "three",
            "four",
            "five",
            "six",
            "seven",
            "eight",
            "nine",
            "ten"
    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.anagram);


        tv_info = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_info);
        tv_word = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_word);
        et_guess = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_guess);
        b_check = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b_check);
        b_check.setOnClickListener(this);
        r = new Random();

        newGame();

    }
    private String shuffleWord(String word) {
        List<String> letters = Arrays.asList(word.split(""));
        Collections.shuffle(letters);
        String shuffled = "";
        for(String letter:letters) {
            shuffled += letter;
        }
        return shuffled;
    }
    private void newGame() {
        //get random word from the dictionary
        currentWord = dictionary[r.nextInt(dictionary.length)];

        //shoow the shuffleword
        tv_word.setText(shuffleWord(currentWord));

        // clear the text
        et_guess.setText("");
        b_check.setEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(et_guess.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(currentWord)) {
            tv_info.setText("Awesome!");
            b_check.setEnabled(false);
            newGame();

            new ParticleSystem(this, 10, R.drawable.star, 3000)
                    .setSpeedByComponentsRange(-0.1f, 0.1f, -0.1f, 0.02f)
                    .setAcceleration(0.000003f, 90)
                    .setInitialRotationRange(0, 360)
                    .setRotationSpeed(120)
                    .setFadeOut(2000)
                    .addModifier(new ScaleModifier(0f, 1.5f, 0, 1500))
                    .oneShot(v, 10);


        } else {
            tv_info.setText("Try Again");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain your question a little bit better? What are the questions you are answering? What are these "random words" ?

Comment: Use a `List<String>` rather than a `String[]` - and call `list.remove(word_or_index)` to remove the word from the list after using it.

Comment: i want to remove the random words so that after i answered each words on dictionary automatic the activity will end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want to remove the word after it has been guessed and then when they are all done, end the game?

---

### Removing guessed words from the array (Hard Way)

The simplest way to do this is to just use a for-loop and set the value to something it can't ever be, like `null` or `""`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < dictionary.length; i++) {
    if(dictionary[i].equalsIgnoreCase(WordToRemove)) {
        dictionary[i] = "";
    }
}
```

Then when you generate your next guess, you need to make sure that the word is valid still:

```
String currentWord = "";
while(!currentWord.equals("")) {
    currentWord = dictionary[r.nextInt(dictionary.length)];
}
```

**Now this is not the best way to achieve the end goal, but it is one way to do it with your setup.**

---

### Removing guessed words from the array (Easy Way)

If we use an `ArrayList<String>` instead of `String[]` then a lot of this work is already done for us. To create and add items to an `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<String> dictionary = new ArrayList<>();
dictionary.add("One");
dictionary.add("Two");
dictionary.add("Three");
dictionary.add("Four");
```

And to remove from an `ArrayList`:

```
dictionary.remove(guessedString);
```

Easier right? Lets see what that would look like in your code:

```
ArrayList<String> dictionary = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    dictionary.add("one");
    dictionary.add("two");
    dictionary.add("three");
    dictionary.add("four");
    ...
}
```

And then removing from the array:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    String guess = et_guess.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
    if(guess.equals(currentWord)) {
        dictionary.remove(guess);
    }
    ...
}
```

Notice however I changed your comparison check too. This is to make sure that we will always find the word in the dictionary. The dictionary **must** contain only lower-case letters for it to work this way as `.remove()` will be case sensitive.

And the last part is picking the new word or deciding the game is over:

```
private void newGame() {
    // Check game state
    if(dictionary.size() < 1) {
        // Do gameover stuff here
        return;
    }

    //get random word from the dictionary
    currentWord = dictionary.get(r.nextInt(dictionary.size()));

    ...
}
```

---

*The `...` sections of code reference your old code that I omitted for sake of brevity and clarity*

Comment: i try this but something error with if(ditionary,size < 1) the word size is on red or error

Comment: `dictionary.size()` its a method in `ArrayList` not a variable (I fixed my answer)

Comment: @jerome If this solved your problem please make sure to mark it as accepted for others that may have a similar issue :)

Comment: after i replace some code. the words didnt show which is "one" which is on jumble words

Comment: Can you add your new code as an edit in your original post so I can see what you have now?

Comment: sorry. i already solve my problem thanks guys i mark this as a good answer

Comment: @jerome sorry, it looks like this answer wasn't marked as accepted. You can do so by clicking the check mark on the top left of the question below the up and down arrows for the score.